# Delete / change Status from CP via Ajax (trigger event)

Tags: plugin-development, events

In a plugin init function I'm listening to `entries.saveEntry` and `entries.deleteEntry`. This works perfectly if I'm editing entries from their detail view. If I 'bulk' change or delete entries, these events are not fired. I saw in the `SetStatusElementAction` class an event called `onSetStatus` is triggered but how can I listen to it? The same goes with the delete action.

Somehow the following doesn't get triggered for me:

```
craft()->on('entries.setStatus', function($event){ dd($event); });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Typically, we'd close something like this as a "bug report". But since this is a long-standing known bug, we'll keep the thread open until it eventually gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug in Craft. **Bulk actions do not trigger their respective events.**

I'm not sure when (if?) a solution will appear. I'm guessing that it won't be fixed in the 2.x branch, since this bug has existed for quite awhile now. With any luck, it'll be fixed when Craft 3 launches.

Answer (score 1):

[Lindsey's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14611/57) is correct, but as a workaround, you can listen to the [onBeforePerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBeforePerformAction) or [onPerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onPerformAction) events, check to see if the action parameter to see if it's the action you're interested in and perform  your logic as necessary.

Comment: How do you get the ID(s) of the element(s) that the action is being performed on?

Comment: @jthomas Can you post that as a new question and I'll answer? Probably helpful to other people, too.

Comment: Yep, I'd be happy to.

Comment: Question and answer here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/get-the-type-of-action-and-the-elementss-that-an-action-is-being-performed-on