# 'onDeleteEntry' Event is not triggered when an Entry is deleted?

Tags: plugin-development, events

I have the following code:

```
namespace Craft;

class AffiliatesExportPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
  //All other functions

  public function init() {
    craft()->on('entries.onDeleteEntry', function(Event $event) {
      Craft::log(" on delete ######\n\n", LogLevel::Info, true);
    });
  }
}
```

I added this as a plugin activated the plugin, but when I delete an entry, it doesn't seem to get triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you delete it? From the entry's edit screen? Or from the entries index screen (via the checkbox)?

Comment: @lindsey-d Through the check boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bulk actions do not trigger their respective events.** When you delete an entry (or multiple entries) via the checkboxes, you are performing a bulk action.

As a workaround, you can listen to the [onBeforePerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBeforePerformAction) or [onPerformAction](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onPerformAction) events, check to see if the action parameter to see if it's the action you're interested in and perform  your logic as necessary. *

> ** Much of this answer was copied from my & Brad's answers on [this similar thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8460/delete-change-status-from-cp-via-ajax-trigger-event)*

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this: craft()->on('entry.onPerformAction ', function(Event $event) {
  Craft::log(" on delete ######\n\n", LogLevel::Info, true);
 }); . Doesn't seem to work, I tried it with just 'onPerformAction' as well, it doesn't work then either.